# RStudio crashes when trying to fit lm Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm attempting to run some code, example from a textbook called "Design and Analysis of Experiments with R". It runs fine using R console or from ESS and Emacs, but in RStudio crashes.  Have I got something set incorrectly?  I've tried other sections of code and anything that seems to fit a model causes it to crash.

Ubuntu 18.04, RStudio 1.1.456, R 3.5.1.  Here is the offending code

```
Example 3 p. 24
rm(bread)
library(daewr)
mod0 <-lm( height ~ time, data = bread )
summary (mod0)
```

Crash screen
[image]

Comment: You might do better by asking at the RStudio support forums